# Is this MySQLi safe?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, statements, procedural

I wanted to do the follow thing with MySQLi statements or PDO but I experienced a lot of errors on my server.

Please check if the follow example to learn code I did myself will be okay for safety and if it is okay to use it. And hopefully the follow code will help new MySQLi users to learn at least how to start with MySQLi:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "db_user";
$password = "db_pass";
$dbname = "db_name";
@ $db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Connection could not be established");
}
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['user']);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM members WHERE profile='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

PROFILE VIEW

   <br>Name: <?php echo $row['nombre']?> ID: <?php echo $row['Age']?> <br />




<?php
}
?>
```

All working fine. If somebody can make it safer, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The safest assumption to make is that user data is always malicious. the second safest assumption is to always use prepared statements with parametrized inputs.

Comment: Please don't caps that. You re-use a variable for 2 different things, I don't call that safe. I would also sanitize the user input more. $query = (""); is valid, but it's not how you would define a string. You can remove the ( and ) around it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for [a codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "db_user";
$password = "db_pass";
$dbname = "db_name";
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 die("Connection could not be established");
}
$username = $_GET['user'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `profile` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetch_row()) { ?>

 <br />Name: <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> ID: <?php echo $row['Age']; ?> <br /><?php
} ?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_row()

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump()` on $query, after the `->execute()`?